# firebase.auth() error in createusermethod in java Script

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

This is my java script for Register page for web using firebase authentication.When i fill the email and password till **Alert message Testing** will execute but firebase.auth()..... it will not execute and the page will get refresh automatically.

```
    var email=document.getElementById("inemail").value;
    var password=document.getElementById("inpass").value;
    var password1=document.getElementById("inpass1").value;
    var lPassword=password.length;
    var lPassword1=password1.length;
    if(lPassword < 7)
    {
        alert("Password Should more than seven Charecter");
        return;
    }

    else if(password!=password1){
        alert("Correctly Enter the Password");
        return;
    }
    else if(password==password1 || lPassword1==lPassword)
    { 
    alert("Testing");
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.toString(),password.toString()).catch(function(error) {
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            if (errorCode == 'auth/weak-password') {
              alert('The password is too weak.');
            } else {
              alert(errorMessage);
            }
            console.log(error);
          });

        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
          if (user) {
            var email = user.email;
            alert("Sucessfully Created");
          } 
          else {
           alert("sorry Try again");
          }

        });

    }

}
```

in This script have any errors?if it have error please help me to find-out.

Comment: you need to use `then` after create the account

Comment: @Ticherhaz again only till alert message 'testing' this script is executing

Comment: @Ticherhaz I hosted the the page in this link  https://smartmonitoring-2ec41.firebaseapp.com  i made the correction but it is not saving properly so please tell me where i made the mistake.

Comment: What do you mean by not saved properly?

Comment: What i made changes in javaScript it is not updating in host.

Comment: After you created account, you need to store the data after that, use `then` again after store the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ticherhaz explains in his comment, your need to use the [`then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) method to detect when the [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) returned by the asynchronous [`createUserWithEmailAndPassword()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#create-user-with-email-and-password) method is fulfilled.

The following should do the trick:

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.toString(),password.toString())
.then(userCredential => {
     var email = userCredential.user.email;
     alert("Sucessfully Created");
})
.catch(function(error) {
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        if (errorCode == 'auth/weak-password') {
          alert('The password is too weak.');
        } else {
          alert(errorMessage);
        }
        console.log(error);
      });
}
```

Note that, as explained in the doc, "on successful creation of the user account, this user will also be signed in to your application", so **you don't need to use the `onAuthStateChanged()` method in this case**.

---

In one of your comments above you say "only till alert message 'testing' this script is executing". Actually, if there is no error with the new user creation, the rejection handler callback passed to `catch()` is not called and therefore you don't get a feedback on the fact that the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` was correctly executed. For that you need the `then()` method.

Comment: I hosted the the page in this link  https://smartmonitoring-2ec41.firebaseapp.com.i made the correction but it is not saving properly so please tell me where i made the mistake